# Pytest parametrization of test for a list generated from cmdline options in conftest.py

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

> I am trying to parametrize a test which is being generated from the
>   cmdline options in conftest.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pytest
import test



def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--low", action="store", type=int, help="low")
    parser.addoption("--high", action="store",type=int,  help="high")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def user(request):
    return request.config.getoption("low")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def rang(request):
    return request.config.getoption("high")




#test_file.py

def data(low, high):
    return list(range(low, high))

@pytest.mark.parametrize("num", data(10, 20))
def test(num):
    assert num < 1000
```

I would like run a command like "pytest --low=10 --high=100 test_file.py". Code is working fine with @pytest.mark.parametrize("num", data(x, y)) for the range of values between x and y. I don't want to provide any values in parametrization other than low and high. If I code something like @pytest.mark.parametrize("num", data(low, high)), it throws an error.  Is there any way I can get this parametrization work? I know code works when we generate list outside of a method. But I want to write a method for generating list and use that list inside parametrization.

Is there any way I can access these low and high cmdline options anywhere in the test_file.py ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parametrize the test using the [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests) hook. Withing the hook, you will have access to the command line args.

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--low", action="store", type=int, help="low")
    parser.addoption("--high", action="store",type=int,  help="high")


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'num' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        lo = metafunc.config.getoption('low')
        hi = metafunc.config.getoption('high')
        metafunc.parametrize('num', range(lo, hi))
```

```
# test_file.py

def test_spam(num):
    assert num
```

Another possibility is to access the args via `pytest.config`, although note that this is a deprecated feature that will be removed soon:

```
import pytest


def data():
    lo = pytest.config.getoption('low')
    hi = pytest.config.getoption('high')
    return list(range(lo, hi))


@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', data())
def test_spam(num):
    assert num
```

Comment: metafunction method is working. Thank you. 

Is there any way we can access pytest arguments in test_xx.py files without fixtures? In older version we used to do that by using namespace but now as it is getting deprecated, is there any other way of accessing these variable values?

I know about def func(low, high), I am looking for some other way.

Comment: Accessing the config object via the `request` fixture looks to be the most anticipated way now. However, no one can stop you from attaching your own attributes to `pytest` module itself, e.g. call `pytest.lo = config.getoption('low')` in `pytest_configure` hook. You can then access the argument via `pytest.lo` anywhere in tests.

Comment: [Looking at the deprecations docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace), attaching your own global vars to `pytest` module seems to be the recommended approach for replacing `pytest_namespace` stuff.

Comment: `pytest_generate_tests` works also from the specific test file, which could be a better placement if used only one place. The if clause does not even seem necessary if there is only one test.